# Server 2012 R2 stuck checking for updates from WSUS server

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, update, wsus, windows-update

I have a 2012 R2 WSUS server, and many 2012 R2 clients.

One of my servers only, completed installing a batch of updates, and now upon every check for updates, it gets stuck "Checking for updates".

The last entry in the WindowsUpdate.log file is as below:

```
2016-12-14  16:13:46:201     732    5b0 AU  User login event timer expired for session id: 1.
2016-12-14  16:13:46:202     732    5b0 AU  WARNING: Failed to get Network Cost info from NLM, assuming network is NOT metered, error = 0x80240037
2016-12-14  16:13:46:202     732    5b0 AU  #############
2016-12-14  16:13:46:202     732    5b0 AU  ## START ##  AU: Install updates
2016-12-14  16:13:46:202     732    5b0 AU  #########
2016-12-14  16:13:46:202     732    5b0 AU    # Initiating scheduled install
2016-12-14  16:13:46:210     732    5b0 AU  WARNING: There are no approved updates to install
2016-12-14  16:13:46:210     732    5b0 AU    # Exit code = 0x8024000C
2016-12-14  16:13:46:210     732    5b0 AU  #########
2016-12-14  16:13:46:210     732    5b0 AU  ##  END  ##  AU: Install updates
2016-12-14  16:13:46:210     732    5b0 AU  #############
```

Wsus reports 4 updates needing to be installed on the server, so I am expecting the client to return that information, and attempt to install those 4 updates.

I have tried running the Windows update trouble shooter, which found two issues and fixed them. I restarted several times, to no avail.

I also tried removing the software distribution folder and retrying, but no change.

I am now running an sfc /scannow now, as well as some DISM /scanhealth and restorehealth commands to check for issues.

Is there anything else I can check to determine why WU forever sits checking for updates? My other servers are all ok.

Comment: `WARNING: There are no approved updates to install` - Have you made sure these updates are approved? Have you checked to see if these updates are hidden on the server?

Comment: The updates are indeed approved. If I run a report against this server, it lists 2 flash security updates, and 2 updates for Windows Server 2012 R2. All have approval status of Install, and status of not installed. I have installed these on other servers today without issue.

Comment: I just ran the troubleshooter again, and it looks to report the same issues again (Service registration is missing or corrupt, and problems installing recent updates), even though the troubleshooter reportedly fixed these on the last run. Should I run through the whole reset process for the update components: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/971058

Comment: Are those updates downloaded to your wsus server? They might be approved but not on the server yet and thus won't install. Add a column to wsus to show that. Do those updates depend on other updates?

Comment: The updates are downloaded, as I have installed them on other servers. They do depend on two prior updates, both of which are installed.

Comment: The server seems to exhibit the same behaviour I have seen on Windows 7 machines after an update the middle of this year, where it sits checking for updates forever, but CPU usage seems to be stuck at 25%, with the usage coming from Service host: local system (Windows update is one of the services this process is managing). Solution for Windows 7 was install July or later CU. Don't think that is an option here though.

Comment: Well the server seems to be doing something, albeit hurrendously slowly! There are now events in the log that seem to indicate it is downloading or attempting to download updates, but the GUI still shows checking for updates. [Pastebin - WULog](http://pastebin.com/HvxRmfYV)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server finally showed me some updates after 2 days of "Checking for updates" and a server restart.